# Django Polls App: OperationalError: attempt to write a read only database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I was going through the tutorial on the Django website.
I got this error while trying to create a Choice Object.

```
>>> q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 714, in create
    return super(RelatedManager, self.db_manager(db)).create(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 372, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 698, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 731, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 921, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
>>>
```

I dont understand what seems to be the problem. I tried changing the permissions for the "db.sqlite3" file to 777.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What operating system is that? Do you have your selinux enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change permissions to the directory that database file is in too.

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct by clicking 'tick' button on the left of it.

Comment: Haha. Didn't know.
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

If running on Mac OS X, make sure to prepend the command with `sudo` (in the command line).